# Use of exit instead of echo changes output mime type

Tags: php, codeigniter

We are using CodeIgniter for our server-side code, and are noticing something strange when returning HTTP codes other than 200.

For HTTP code 200, the code we are using does

```
echo $output;
```

and allows more output to be appended.

For HTTP code 403 (for example), the code we are using does:

```
exit($output);
```

Our server generally returns JSON responses, so the mime type is explicitly set to be `application/json`.

That works fine (on the client) for status codes of 200, but when the error (and `exit`) version is used, the mime type is reset to `text/html`.

Does anyone know anything about why CodeIgiter might reset the mime type in this case ?

Comment: Just a site note, you shouldn't use parentheses after `echo` since it is not a function, but a language construct. See http://php.net/echo.

Comment: :-) Yes, I wasn't copying code, just trying to make it look pretty. I've edited it to be correct (the actual code already is).

Comment: Peter, usually "correct" *is* the prettiest way to do things.

Comment: :-) Couldn't agree more.

Comment: you can use `$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');` in controller, it sets the content type of output buffer. [referance](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html) moreover you can set headers too if needed.

Comment: @karanthakkar : Yes, that's what we are doing. If I print out in debug immediately before the `exit` the content type is set to `application/json`, however the *actual* content type is set to `text/html`. The same thing does not happen with the `echo` branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that code igniter uses output buffering to capture everything that's being echo'd, and set the mimetype *and* send the output after you've composed the full response body.

In the exit() case you completely termininate everything, so if code igniter does anything of this stuff *after* the controller logic, it will never get a chance to set the correct mime-type in the first place.

In general you should avoid calls to `exit()` unless you have a very specific reason for it.

Comment: While I can't confirm this, this is along the same lines as I was thinking.

Comment: OK. That confirms my suspicion.  Thanks for the feedback, much appreciated. I'll leave it until tomorrow before ticking, in case someone comes back with another idea.

Comment: "Tomorrow" finally came. :(